# Google Play Services - Admob's AdView is final

Tags: admob

I am porting to new GPS Admob.

I had overrided AdView like that.

```
class AdView1 extends AdView{



    public AdView1(Activity activity, AdSize adSize, String adUnitId) {
        super(activity);
        adView.setAdUnitId(adUnitId);
        adView.setAdSize(adSize);
    }

    int bannerHeight;
    boolean bannerShown;



    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        bannerHeight = h;
        if(bannerShown){
            SetBannerHeight1(bannerHeight);             
        }
    }

}
```

But now `AdView` is final.

What is best way to get AdView height?

I know there are following methods
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView.html#getAdSize()
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdSize.html

But I do not know when it is the best time to call these.

e.g.
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener.html#onAdLoaded()
or
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener.html#onAdOpened()

Comment: I suspect you going the wrong way about a standard use case. Why do you need to get the bannerHeight?